# Using xtrabackup backup to recover MyISAM data

Tags: mysql, backup, myisam

1. Why do I have a ibdata1 file when backing up MyISAM data?  I don't have a InnoDB table.
2. I can't find anything about recovering MyISAM data on the official website.  How Do Irestore a single backup of a MyISAM database?
3. When using partial backup, when the parameter ‘--databases’ is invalid, it will also prompt for completion. Is this a bug?
4. xtrabackup backup MyISAM data, can you lock only tables that need to be backed up without using global locks ?

Answer (score 0):

1. if so ibdata1 is rather small. It doesn't matter. Consider it there ready for when you need to use innodb.
2. xtrabackup is, full, incremental, but partial backups seem to be only [innodb](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/xtrabackup_bin/partial_backups.html) (its innodb focus of xtrabackup seems to explain the restriction rather than an intentional excluding of myisam).
3. You should show the full command line, server version and xtrabackup version.
4. Doesn't seem to be implemented.

Of course the general advice is, use innodb, there is rarely a downside (normally just need to allocation a innodb_buffer_pool_size), and has the benefit that it can backup without any table locks or global locks.

Comment: thanks,   i am using Percona Xtrabackup 2.4.19，the database version is MySQL 5.7.29.     use command  ' innobackupex --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --user=root --password=*** --databases="no database exists"  full ',  the database does not exist, and the result is success